# HTML with no framework : how to change the font-family to Local Font

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML file with no framework (written in Notepad), I have a font file that I have physically located.
I're trying to change the font family to it but it's not working.
The relative location of the file is correct (when I attach an xml file to the same relative location it is fine)
When I check in f12 I see the font but in practice it does not really affect.
Anyone know such a problem?

HTML file:
[image]

in F12:

[image]

Comment: I guess it should be: `src: "C:/Users/...`

Comment: I tried of course but it does not work
I added a clearer picture

Comment: try `src: local("CSL-Hadassah"), url("./font/CSL-Hadassah.ttf");`. The local font-face has to match the font-family name. Also `./font` for correct relative path. If it still doesn't work, check if the font is at the correct place. it sould be in a font folder next to your index.(x)html file...

Comment: I do not have index.html, it is a single file without a framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check that the font you want supports the language in which the text is written